# Ecospold Identifiers for ecoinvent 3.2

Tags: brightway

Can you use the SQlite database created in Brightway2 for ecoinvent 3.2 (for example) and find original spold file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can! It is in the cleverly disguised key `filename`, e.g.

```
In [1]: from brightway2 import *

In [2]: projects.current = "3.2"

In [3]: act = Database("ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff").random()

In [4]: act['filename']
Out[4]: '1452cc84-e08d-4c92-a8c4-e0644736399b_b8e7c209-349c-4f20-956b-533119feab30.spold'
```